# thread print name with runnable parameter

Tags: java

hi guys I'm trying to learn the basics of java multithreading, while studying  I had found this exercise

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable rrr = () -> Thread.currentThread().setName(args[0]);
        new print(rrr).start();
    }
}
```

The exercise asks to implement the print class so that the following test print the value of args[0]

```
 public class print extends Thread{

     public print(Runnable rrr) {
     }

     public void run()
     {
          System.out.println("run() called by " +      Thread.currentThread().getName());
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
     }
 }
```

This is my implementation, is right?

Comment: the `Runnable rrr` parameter is nowhere used. So the code isn't executed anywhere. You'd need to store it in a variable then do `rrr.run()` in the other `run()` method.

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: @lucagianni, what kind of systax is this Runnable rrr = () -> Thread.currentThread().setName(args[0]);

Comment: @ShamithaSilva A Java8 Lambda expression

Comment: @zapl, I'm feeling old now.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Runnable rrr` parameter is nowhere used. So the code isn't executed anywhere. You'll need to change the code to something like

```
 public class print extends Thread{

     private Runnable rrr;
     public print(Runnable rrr) {
         this.rrr = rrr;
     }

     public void run()
     {
          rrr.run(); // this runs "Thread.currentThread().setName(args[0])"
          System.out.println("run() called by " +      Thread.currentThread().getName());
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

     }
 }
```

to have it work.

---

Simpler approach:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    System.out.println("Thread name is " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
});
t.setName("Peter");
t.start();
```

> Thread name is Peter

Comment: with this I receive this error Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at Test.lambda$main$0(Test.java:11)
 at print.run(print.java:23)

Comment: @lucagianni means you didn't start the program with parameters. Unlike in script languages, [0] is not the program name but the actual first parameter.

Comment: so with a command line argument then the error will not appear?

Comment: @lucagianni yes if you pass a command line parameter to the java programm, then that will be chosen as the first parameter via `args[0]` and will thus be printed as the threadname to the console

Answer (score 0):

No need for Runnable for the constructor when a thread starts it directly call run method

Comment: can you explain me more?

Comment: when calling start method on a Thread object the run method is called automatically,so the code you want to execute should go only in run method and it is called automatically when you call start method